# iOS + Heroku Parse Server: "Facebook auth is invalid for this user."

Tags: ios

I have an application which is using a Parse server on Heroku. I got a problem when I login with Facebook in my application and then go in the browser and change the password for this FB account and also check "sign out from all other devices".

When I go back in the application and I try to save [PFUser currentUser] I got error code 101: Facebook auth is invalid for this user.
I automatically logout the user , but signing in again with Facebook doesn't fix this.

Also it's very weird because if I delete the application and install it again this error will keep appearing.

What I can do to fix this? I already tried to add FACEBOOK_APP_ID in heroku server variables but it was for nothing. Also tried to delete the local facebook cached accessToken.

It seems that I get the same facebook accessToken each time I try to login with Facebook.

I am using this code to login with Facebook:

```
[PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions: ...]
```

Later edit: It seems that the parse sever version had this problem, after updating it the problem is solved.

Comment: If you add your later edit as an answer, not only can you accept it, but I will upvote it. You saved my day and I thank you. Totally forgot to look and see what parse server version I was running. If I could buy you a beer, I would.